# Pandas DateTime Formating

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to figure out how to reformat a date in a pandas df.  The source date is a string in the format of %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.  I use the following code to convert it do a date field in a format=%Y-%m-%d.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.date
```

How do I convert a date field in the format of %Y-%m-%d into %m/%d/%Y ?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Have you read date/time formatting docs?

Answer (score 1):

i think this should help

```
 df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.date
 df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

you can try a one liner

```
 df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: I actually tried this, however when the data is exported into excel the date is in a string format so the normal filter functions don't work. strftime converts the date to string does it not? My goal is to keep it in date format, so the filtering works in excel. @mohsinali

Comment: well after we do that we can do the  df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')